# Performing an Action with Text Located in TextArea, UIWebView

Tags: iphone, user-interface, sdk, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

So right now I have a ViewController with UIWebView and a button. When the button is clicked it allows the user to email whatever I specify. For this occasion, there is going to be a textarea box (at a certain URL) inside the UIWebView. I want to be able to grab that text inside the textarea box and name it *txtNotes*, so I can use the following code to send the text inside the textarea via Apple's email interface:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"My TextArea"];

    NSString *emailBody = self->txtNotes.text;
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

So how would I grab the text from inside the textarea and name it as an object "txtNotes" in Xcode. Please also include code examples!

Thanks!

Comment: Ok.. I deleted my answer so that other won't mislead by my answer. I read your answer twice again after your comment. It was my mistake. I apprehended wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your HTML should include an id for the textarea for example

```
<textarea id='myTextAreaId'></textarea>
```

then you can perform this handy JS to Objective-C call to snatch the textarea.

```
NSString *txtNotes = [NSString stringWithString:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('myTextAreaId').value"]];
```